# как вставить ArrayList<MyClass> в SQLite

Tags: android, json, sqlite

есть необходимость положить ArrayList в SQLite, пробовал вот так :

```
public void updateTable(ArrayList list) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("list_s", new JSONArray(list));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String sList = jsonObject.toString();
}
```

вызов метода происходит так:

```
updateTable(maps);
```

Тип входного объекта такой:

```
ArrayList<DataModel> maps;
```

на выходе получаю:

```
sList: {"list_s":["com.my.TestP.DataModel@41b75c98"]}
```

и кажется, что видимо я не верно сохраняю... как правильно, подскажите?

Comment: Такой тип сохранения применим к спискам имеющий более простой вариант, например ArrayList<String>, но не со списками , включающие в себя кастомные объекты. Скорей всего, перед записью вам надо будет как-то сюреализовать ваши объекты, привести их к более простой и читабельной форме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тебе нужно все поля твоего класса сохранять в бд отдельно, 
В таблице создаешь поля такиеже как и у твоего класса и сохраняешь туда все.
А при выборке в цикле получаешь данные формируешь объект и засовываешь в ArrayList. Или если так не хочешь делать, можешь заюзать к примеру realm.io

Comment: а если у меня множество значений будет в Arraylist  мне потом надо связать их с основной таблицей, и как тогда быть?
например: основная таблица: поле1, поле2, поле3, так вот поле3 содержать должен быть этот список,  если я создам отдельную таблицу, и в нее буду записывать все поля List, то потом мне надо связать поле3 с теми полями, которые есть в таблице2, и что должно быть в поле 3 тогда?

Comment: Ну это уже связи таблиц, нужно почитать о свзях. По хорошему тебе нужно завести в основной таблице поле к примеру id_second, и передавать туда id из второй таблице.

Comment: а сериализация в данном примере не вариант?  тут выше подсказали смотреть в эту сторону? какие +/- использования сериализации в данном примере?

Comment: Не уверен что правильный подход